# What does the constant $(\mu)$ mean in the formula $B=\mu(N/L)I\,?$

Tags: electromagnetism

In the formula $B=\mu (N/L)I,$ what is the number of the constant $\mu$ for copper?
I need to know because I did an experiment where we created an electromagnet and changed the diameter of the wire. We measured the magnetic field using a Pasco sensor. I want to prove this data is correct by manually calculating the strength of the magnetic field. Bear in mind this is year 11 physics so it isn't that complex yet.

Comment: Magnetic permeability   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, $\mu$ is a stand-in for *$\mu_0\,k$*. Here $\mu_0$ is a constant $4\pi\times10^{-7}\:\mathrm{T/(A\:m)}$ and $k$ is the relative permeability of the material used for the core of the solenoid.

For example, with Fe, it is around $200\:\mathrm{N/A}^2$. Whatever material your core is, just look up the relative permeability for that substance and multiply by $\mu_0$. That will give you the $\mu$ value in your equation B = $\mu(N/L)I$. (From what I've found $\mu_0$ for Cu is $0.9999\:\mathrm{N/A}^2$.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I've never seen that before.

Comment: That is highly nonstandard notation for the relative permeability of the material (unless you can provide sources). The much more usual notation is $\mu_r$.

Comment: $\mu_r$ instead of *k*? I've never actually studied this other than by looking around the internet so I would trust your word over mine. I've always seen it as *k* though (http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/solenoid.html  here for example)

Comment: I'm finding conflicting results on the relative permeability of iron (which is what my core is). One site (http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Workshop/advice/coils/mu/#mur) says for iron that is 99.8% pure it is 5000 while another site (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S001600322890558X) is giving a few other number liek 1150 or 250

Comment: Wait i think I just realized, please confirm. Is mu for the formula 6.28*10^-3. Should I just substitute 6.28*10^-3 into μ in the formula  B = μ(N/L)I

Comment: No, it $\mu_0$ and $\mu$ are different. $\mu_0$ is a constant (which I have provided) while $\mu$ is that constant times the relative permeability of your core. I too have found conflicting results on the *k* (or $\mu_r$) value of iron though. I'll keep looking to see if I can find where the discrepancy in results comes from. And where did you get 6.28e-3 from?

Comment: When I took the constant 4π×10−7 and multiplied it by 5000 (which is the relative permeability (μr) for iron according to some sites I got 6.28*10^-3 which is μ according to that site. (http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Workshop/advice/coils/mu/#mur)

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Yes, that would be the $\mu$ in your equation.